# Javascript constructor functions vs Typescript classes

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning Javascript and trying to wrap my head around few important concepts. As per my understanding till now, Javascript does not have classes, it uses constructor functions instead of classes to create blueprint for the objects. Example:

```
// javascript code
var Car = function() {
  // this is a private variable
  var speed = 10;

  // these are public methods
  this.accelerate = function(change) {
    speed += change;
  };

  this.decelerate = function() {
    speed -= 5;
  };

  this.getSpeed = function() {
    return speed;
  };
};
```

```
// typescript code
class Car {

  public speed: number = 10;

  public acceleration(accelerationNumber: number): void {
    this.speed += accelerationNumber;
  }

  public decelerate(decelerateNumber: number): void {
    this.speed += decelerateNumber;
  }

  public getSpeed(): number {
    return this.speed;
  }
}
```

The above Typescript code makes much more sense because we have a class that creates a blueprint for that class objects. But, in Javascript this blueprint is being created with a function. So does that mean constructor function in Javascript does the same thing that classes does in Typescript/Java/etc.?

Comment: Those two aren't exactly equivalent. The Javascript version should be using the `prototype` to define the methods and put `speed` on `this.speed`.

Comment: Yes. Your "class" will be transformed int function(){} which will be called with keyword new. This is smth like syntax sugar. But in ES6 classes will be come as standard (bu as a sugar also).
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/

Comment: "Javascript does not have classes" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes Are you referring to literally or that the implementation of javascript classes is architecturally different to other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equivalent to that Typescript class would be:

```
var Car = function () {
  this.speed = 10;
};

Car.prototype.accelerate = function (change) {
  this.speed += change;
};

Car.prototype.decelerate = function () {
  this.speed -= 5;
};

Car.prototype.getSpeed = function () {
  return this.speed;
};
```

The `Car` function, the constructor function, is basically what `constructor()` is in a `class`; it is what is executed to initialise a new instance. All functions on `prototype` are the other methods defined inside the class shared by all instances.

Comment: Thanks @deceze! But if we have a constructor function 'Car', where is the class defined then? Because as per my knowledge, the constructor functions are used to create new objects of a class. Where is the class defined in this case?

Comment: It isn't. The magic is in the `new` keyword. It constructs a new object, initialises it with the constructor function, and ensures that it inherits things from `prototype`. This really isn't much different from what happens in most other OO languages, it's just not expressed with a syntax that uses the keyword `class`. You're actually seeing a bit more in detail how the sausage gets made in Javascript.

Comment: The prototype object acts as the template. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes